# Workday SOAP API - Download event document

Tags: soap, workday-api

I'm using [Launch Integration](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Integrations/v40.2/Launch_Integration.html) which produces a PDF. When I used [Get Event Documents](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Integrations/v40.2/Get_Event_Documents.html), I can see a reference to the PDF that's created (including the file name, type, WID, and Document_ID), but it does not include the file itself (in Base64).

I expected to receive a Base64 stream of the document that I can save as the file. Is there another API call I should be making instead to access the file stream?

Edit: I do not have access to Workday Studio, only the API endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to achieve this by using the following REST API endpoint: `{{base_url}}/ccx/cc-blobitory/{{tenant}}/{{DocumentID}}`, where the DocumentID was formatted `cloud/ABC...123`. Hope this is useful for others!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in Workday Studio, you can use the Repository Document Document_ID field to retrieve the document.

Split the Document_ID on the "/" character like this:
[image]

Then, you can use the Retrieve mediation step to get the document from the repository.
[image: retrieve]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Wyatt! Unfortunately, I'm a developer outside of Workday, so I'm only able to use the Workday SOAP and REST APIs; I don't have access to Studio. Do you know of any other way to access this document with those APIs after the integration process produces it?